# QPDF bad for WIndows?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, 64-bit, pdfedit

I spent hours trying to install QPDF on my computer (Windows 10) just to see this. Is QPDF bad for windows or is this some technical error? How can I fix this? Because I badly need to edit some pdf files.
[image: Screenshot saying, "Windows protected your PC.")]

Comment: The important text part is `unrecognized app` - it simply means that the app is not widely used. Furthermore you should never ever install a program into `C:\Windows\System32` or a subfolder!

Comment: Windows Defender displays this message when the amount of users who have ran a specific version of that executable is so low, it cannot determine if the application is safe, if you trust the application you should run the application.  It also means nobody bothered to report the application as safe.

Comment: Where (URL) did you obtain QPDF from?  What version of QPDF are you trying to install?  Is `qpdf.exe` digitally code-signed by a trusted publisher?  That `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` file seems a bit suspicious to me, since it doesn't exist (or is renamed) in the latest release of QPDF.

Comment: @leeharvey1 i downloaded it from the link provided in github. followed the instructions.. i think i shouldnt have any problem using it now

Answer (score 0):

As long as you trust the program, cou can click on *More Info* and let Windows run the application. If you are not 100% sure, you can always scan the whole program folder with any anti virus software, but keep in mind that not every virus can be 100% detected.

QPDF has an github repo where you also can review the code in any case. If you downloaded QPDF through a reputable source than the probability of an infected Programm is low.

But keep in mind, that any installation should always happen in C:\Program Files. If you want to run the program more quickly you can link it in system32 but it's not recommended.

Comment: i downloaded it from the original link..the github one.. i guess using it should be fine